# Apache combine basic auth logins for both proxy and directories

Tags: apache-2.4, login

I'm using Apache as a front for Grafana and am using the basicauth to log onto the server. The server also has several files in a directory that I want to access through basicauth. I can make both happen separately, but I would like to log in only once, instead of having to enter the username and password for both uses. The segment below is used to make the Grafana login happen. What can I do to also make the same login gain access to a directory? Is this even possible at all?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@authproxy
    ServerName authproxy
    ErrorLog "logs/authproxy-error_log"
    CustomLog "logs/authproxy-access_log" common


    <Proxy *>
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName GrafanaAuthProxy
        AuthBasicProvider file
        AuthUserFile C:\path-to-htpasswdfile
        Require valid-user

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteRule .* - [E=PROXY_USER:%{LA-U:REMOTE_USER},NS]
        RequestHeader set X-WEBAUTH-USER "%{PROXY_USER}e"

    </Proxy>

    RequestHeader unset Authorization

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://tolocalserver/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://tolocalserver/
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible. Give the other area the same basic auth configuration as you have for the Grafana area:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName GrafanaAuthProxy
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile C:\path-to-htpasswdfile
Require valid-user
```

Then the same Authorization header sent by the client will allow them into both areas. Note that the value of `AuthName` has to be the same in both areas, so if you don't want to use `GrafanaAuthProxy` for both, you should change it to a different value.

You'll also need to (1) remove the `RequestHeader unset Authorization` directive; not sure why that's there; and (2) add exceptions to the `<Proxy *>` directive for the other URL area.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me out. The RequestHeader unset Authorization is there according to the Grafana documentation:

The RequestHeader unset Authorization removes the Authorization header from the HTTP request before it is forwarded to Grafana. This ensures that Grafana does not try to authenticate the user using these credentials (BasicAuth is a supported authentication handler in Grafana).

If I remove it the login on the Grafana server does not work anymore unfortunately.

Comment: I see. So maybe just move it inside the `<Proxy>` section? Just so it doesn't interfere with the authentication on the other URLs.

Comment: I figured that would be a logical way to do it so I have tried that before. Unfortunately Apache does not allow <Directory> inside <Proxy> so that is not possible.